# How to get shared instance of location manger in synchronize

Tags: objective-c, cllocationmanager, synchronized, locationmanager, background-task

Hy, I want to get the background location updates, so I wrote the below code and make it synchronized to keep it safe from multithreading. So I have two questions:

- Do I really need to synchronize the piece of code, all I am doing in    App is just running background task? I never created any special    `NSThread` type to support multithreading and don't require as such?
- Whenever I need to start the location updates, I call like this:

  ```
  CLLocationManager *locationManager = [LocationTracker sharedLocationManager];
  locationManager.delegate = self;
  [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
  ```

  Is correct way to call?

  ```
  + (CLLocationManager *)sharedLocationManager {
  static CLLocationManager *_locationManager;
  @synchronized(self) {
      if (_locationManager == nil) {

          _locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
          _locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBestForNavigation;
          [_locationManager requestAlwaysAuthorization];
          _locationManager.distanceFilter = 10;

          if(IS_OS_9_OR_LATER){
              _locationManager.allowsBackgroundLocationUpdates = YES;
          }
      }
  }
    return _locationManager;
  }
  ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shared instance should be synchronised. You can use `@Synchronized` or `dispatch_once`. It is good practice to synchronised the shared instances even you are not using the multiple threads.

```
+ (instancetype)sharedLocationManager {

      static LocationTracker *sharedInstance_ = NULL;
      static dispatch_once_t onceToken;

      dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        sharedInstance_ = [[LocationTracker alloc] init];
        [sharedInstance_ initialize];
     });

    return sharedInstance_;
}

- (void)initialize {
          _locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
          _locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBestForNavigation;
         [_locationManager requestAlwaysAuthorization];
          _locationManager.distanceFilter = 10;

         if(IS_OS_9_OR_LATER){
            _locationManager.allowsBackgroundLocationUpdates = YES;
         }
}
```

You can implement the location manager delegates inside the `LocationTracker` class. Use `NSNotificationObserver` to update all the classes, which are all expecting location update.

Else follow the below line.

```
CLLocationManager *locationManager = [LocationTracker sharedLocationManager].locationManager;
locationManager.delegate = self;
[locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
```

Comment: yes, I implemented the delegates inside location tracker. I have one more doubt will it bypass the initializing code 'dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        sharedInstance_ = [[LocationTracker alloc] init];
        [sharedInstance_ initialize];
     });'   if I call  [LocationTracker sharedLocationManager] the second time.

Comment: dispatch_once block will execute only one time. So even you are calling multiple time of [LocationTracker sharedLocationManager]. Initialization will happen only once

Comment: what will be in the case of synchronized?

Comment: synchronized will make sure your block of code accessed by only one thread at a time. Inside a block you are checking if (_locationManager == nil) this will fail for the second time because _locationManager is static variable.

Comment: so will _locationManager as static variable carrying all properties when called sharedLocationManager-method the second time? like desired accuracy etc?

Comment: Yes.It will configure only once. Because of only one time memory allocation (Shared instance)